# python build graph with notes

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I want to build a directed graph and subscribe edges.

```
import os
import scipy as sc
import pylab
import networkx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx import *
from numpy import *

G=networkx.DiGraph()
R=[('S0','S1'),('S1','S2'),('S1','S7'),('S2','S3'),('S2','S6'),('S3','S4'),('S3','S6'),('S4','S5'),('S5','S6'),('S6','S7'),('S7','S8'),('S7','S5'),('S8','Sk') ] 

G.add_edges_from([ (2,3,) ])
G.add_edges_from(R) 
networkx.draw_circular(G)

plt.show()
plt.savefig("path.png");
```

Now I have done this. I built a graph, but I cannot  think up how to subscribe edges. For example I want to mark `S0` and `S1` edge like `"565"`, etc. It will make it more visual and demostrative. 
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of layouting and drawing in one single step (`networkx.draw_circular(G)`), you can layout and draw nodes, edges, node labels and edge labels separately. Here's a small example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.DiGraph()
R=[('S0','S1'),('S1','S2'),('S1','S7'),('S0','S7')] 

G.add_edges_from(R)

# Calculate layout and get all positions
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

# Draw everything
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, 
    {
        ('S0', 'S1'): 'edge1',
        ('S1', 'S2'): 'edge2',
        ('S1', 'S7'): 'edge3',
        ('S0', 'S7'): 'edge4'
    }
)

plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("path.png");
plt.show()
```

For more information about what parameters can be passed to the different drawing functions, [check the documentation](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/drawing.html).

Comment: hm. I should think over your solution too. you did it better than I. So + you

Answer (score 1):

You can draw nodes and egdes selectively with:

```
# nodes
networkx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, pos, nodelist=[list of the nodes])
# edges
networkx.draw_networkx_edges(graph, pos, edgelist=[list of edges])
```

There are more options at http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.nx_pylab

Comment: it's nice. But I want to subscribe edges. I have edges already. I want to subscribe them.

Answer (score 1):

well, I wanted to do this: [image]
and I did it. i.e. I wanted to mark edges. It seems simple, but it wasn't so. Really.

full image is here http://s019.radikal.ru/i603/1204/2a/921bc6badfae.png

```
 import os
 import scipy as sc
 import pylab
 import networkx 
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from networkx import *
 from numpy import *

 G=networkx.DiGraph()
 R=[('S0','S1'),('S1','S2'),('S1','S7'),('S2','S3'),('S2','S6'),('S3','S4'),('S3','S6'),('S4','S5'),('S5','S6'),('S6','S7'),('S7','S8'),('S7','S5'),('S8','Sk') ] 
 G.add_edges_from(R) 
 label={R[1]:'a',R[2]:'b',R[3]:'c'}
 networkx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos=networkx.graphviz_layout(G),edge_labels=label)
 networkx.draw_graphviz(G)
 plt.show()
 plt.savefig("path.png");
```